# The roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are $\beta$ and $n\beta$, show that $(n+1)^2ac=nb^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are $\beta$ and $n\beta$, show that $(n+1)^2ac=nb^2$

Don't really know where to get started with this problem.

Things I've looked at so far are the sum of roots: $\beta+n\beta \Rightarrow \beta(1+n)$ and product of roots: $n\beta^2$

Still quite stumped as to demonstrating what the question asks to show.

Comment: What does it mean to say the equation ... are blah and blah?

Comment: Did you mean "the roots of the equation" at the start there?

Comment: @JBKing, I did indeed mean that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have sum of the roots to be
$$\beta + n \beta = -b/a \implies \beta(n+1) = -b/a$$
Similarly, we have the product of the root to be
$$\beta \cdot (n \beta) = c/a \implies n \beta^2 = c/a$$
Eliminating $\beta$, we obtain that
$$n\left(-\dfrac{b}{a(n+1)}\right)^2 = \dfrac{c}a \implies nb^2 = ca(n+1)^2$$